# Get result based on probability distribution

Tags: php, math

In a browser game we have items that occur based on their probabilities.

P(i1) = 0.8

P(i2) = 0.45

P(i3) = 0.33

P(i4) = 0.01

How do we implement a function in php that returns a random item based on its probability chance?

### edit

The items have a property called rarity which varies from 1 to 100 and represents the probability to occcur. The item that occurs is chosen from a set of all items of a certain type. (e.x the given example above represents all artifacts tier 1)

Comment: Is it intentional that your probabilties sum to more than 1?

Comment: well each item has a property called rarity which varies from 1 to 100, i guess it is not really a probability distribution question then.

Comment: Is it the case where at each step you have to randomly generate a single item based on its probability??

Comment: I have to choose one item from all available based on its probability. The process is as follows: 1. fetch all items based on input parameters (ex all tier 1 artifacts) 2. from them choose the ONE that beats the odds of the other items to occur

Comment: I am not entirely sure what all that means. Normally to generate occurrence of an event with probability P(E) I would generate a random sample X from a uniform distribution and accept the event if X < P(E). If they summed to 1 you could partition [0,1] based on the probabilities but in this case something seems not quite right

Comment: I think the problem is not that "mathematical". You can see what I needed below (thanks to Bulk). I cannot experess my thoughts in formulas but I think the prolbem here is that the probability of an item to occur varies with the number of items in the set. So what I wrote in the question is not exactly P in the mathematical sense but more like percent chance something to occur, which is actually probability...(I am confused now).Sorry if I mislead you . At least I have a solution. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if its the best solution but when I had to solve this a while back this is what I found:

Function taken from [this blog post](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2008/12/10/fast-weighted-random-choice-in-php/):

```
// Given an array of values, and weights for those values (any positive int) 
// it will select a value randomly as often as the given weight allows. 
// for example:
// values(A, B, C, D)
// weights(30, 50, 100, 25)
// Given these values C should come out twice as often as B, and 4 times as often as D. 
function weighted_random($values, $weights){ 
    $count = count($values); 
    $i = 0; 
    $n = 0; 
    $num = mt_rand(0, array_sum($weights)); 
    while($i < $count){
        $n += $weights[$i]; 
        if($n >= $num){
            break; 
        }
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $values[$i]; 
}
```

Example call:

```
$values = array('A','B','C');
$weights = array(1,50,100);

$weighted_value = weighted_random($values, $weights);
```

It's somewhat unwieldy as obviously the values and weights need to be supplied separately but this could probably be refactored to suit your needs.

Comment: @chosta No problem! Feel free to select this as the correct answer if you are happy to do so :)

Comment: I normally wait for a while, but since you saved me precious time I will give it to you.

Comment: You can always change it if something better comes along, I won't mind ;) thanks

Comment: The (value, weight) pairs have to be ordered by ascending weight, right?

Comment: `$num = mt_rand(0, array_sum($weights));`    doubles the probability of 'A'.  It should be `mt_rand(1, array...` test with these code 
`$values = array('A','B','C');
$weights = array(1,50,100);

$count = array();
$n = 100000;
for ($i = 0; $i < $n;$i++) {
 $weighted_value = weighted_random($values, $weights);
 $count[$weighted_value]++;
}
printf("%f, %f, %f", $count['A']/$n,$count['B']/$n,$count['C']/$n);`

Answer (score 0):

Tried to understand how Bulk's function works, and here is how I understand based on Benjamin Kloster answer:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150616/return-random-list-item-by-its-weight

Generate a random number n in the range of 0 to sum(weights), in this case $num so lets say from this: weights(30, 50, 100, 25).

Sum is 205.

Now $num has to be 0-30 to get A,

30-80 to get B

80-180 to get C

and 180-205 to get D

While loop finds in which interval the $num falls.